# $\sqrt{I}=R \iff I=R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, radicals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $I$ and ideal. I have a proof that $\sqrt{I}=R \iff I=R$ and I am wondering if its correct:

"$\Leftarrow$":Obvious, since $I\subset \sqrt{I}$

"$\Rightarrow$":We know that $\sqrt{I}=\bigcap{p_i}$ where $p_i$ is prime and $p_i\supset I$ for all $i$. Because $\bigcap{p_i}=R$ we get that there isn't any proper prime ideal containing $I$ and because each proper ideal is contained in a (proper) maximal ideal we get that $I$ is maximal.

Let $x \in R\setminus I$. Then by maximality of $I$ we have $xI=R$. But this means that $x$ is invertible and therefore also $x^n$. Since $x \in \sqrt{I}\Rightarrow x^n \in I$  we have that $I=R$ since it contains an invertible ellement.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How about just "$1^n\in I$ for some $n$" for $\implies$?

Comment: I'm a beginner in ring theory so I was wondering, what does $\sqrt{I}$ mean?

Comment: @Arthur .Aaah it is so obvious. Of course. Thanks :) !

Comment: @Math_QED This set contains all the elements $x$ where $x^n \in R$ for some $n$.

Comment: Okay thanks. Good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much simpler to use the definition: if $\sqrt{I}=R$, then $1\in\sqrt{I}$, so $1^n\in I$, for some $n$.

Your proof is incorrect. From $\bigcap_i p_i=R$ you argue that $I$ is maximal, which is wrong. You should instead argue that there is *no* prime ideal containing $I$. Therefore $I$ is not a proper ideal.

Comment: What I had in mind is that since $I$ is not contained in any prime ideal (therefore in any maximal ideal) the is it itself maximal or the whole $R$.Anyway thanks for the answer !

Comment: @NickA. If $I$ is not contained in any maximal ideal, it cannot be maximal because it is contained in itself.